# python 2.5 is not supported in 'e' partition

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.5

I'm a novice to development with app engine and I'm trying to upload an application with 
`appcfg.py`, this application is written with `python 2.5`.

When I try to upload the application I get this error:

> ```
> Error 400: --- begin server output ---
> python 2.5 is not supported in 'e' partition
> ```

Kindly find below the command that I use:

> appcfg.py --oauth2 update --no_cookies "PATH TO THE APPLICATION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set up your application to run in an EU datacentre? If so, you can't use python2.5. If you really want to use 2.5, you'll have to create a new application and choose the US location, but you'll need to upgrade to 2.7 pretty soon anyway.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but where can I configure that at creation ?

Answer (score 3):

When creating new Google Cloud project. When google asks for projectname and appid you must click "show advanced settings". There you can select data center location NA or EU.

If someone stumbles into this question with python27 you might have misconfigured app.yaml file, as many examples have **runtime: python** ... not **runtime: python27**

See [details from official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles)

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Don't understand why python doesn't just default to python27 in EU data center though. BTW, I also had to add `threadsafe: no` after this fix and getting a new error *threadsafe must be present and set to either "yes" or "no"*. (Since I didn't do anything to make sure it's actually threadsafe, I chose no as a safe default.)

Comment: Glad I could be of help :) And yes, examples does not include the treadsafe: no/yes tag in the app.yaml so you have to add it there yourself nowdays...